# Refactoring iOS project to NOT use storyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

As my project is getting larger & more complex, I'm finding the use of storyboards to become unmanageable. My storyboard file is getting large, my need to reuse components/entire views in the app is growing, and the need to jump from on screen, to a totally different screen is becoming difficult without having a tangled mess of segues all across my storyboard.

I've started to do simple things like push/pop/present modal viewcontrollers in code like this:

```
UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init]; // usually a custom subclass of uiviewcontroller
[vc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But I'm looking for advice on how to take this further.

For example: I'd like to be able to switch from one tab, to another tab's 3rd view controller in the navigation controller stack. In storyboards, I could simply drag a segue between the two view controllers. Without storyboards, I could set the selected index on my tabcontroller, then push controllers in the new tab's selected index until i'm at the one I want? Something like:

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2]; // then how do I get deep inside the new tab controller's view heirarchy?
```

Really, I'm just looking for articles/advice on how to refactor a large project that uses storyboards into a project that does not use storyboards. I'm already finding the project easier to manage, easier to reuse components, and easier to control without the storyboards. Just need a little more advice/practice to finish this transition.

Thanks

Comment: I arrived at a similar point to you with a large project. I am happily continuing with the use of storyboards for my basic UI framework, and code segues to maintain a "clean" storyboard interface. I use view controller storyboard IDs a lot with custom segues. Does this compromised solution sound interesting to you, or do you definitely want to eliminate SB altogether?

Comment: The state you described is pretty much where I'm at now. My storyboard is used for basic app workflow layout. However, this starts to become unmaintainable as more screens are being added, and the need for multiple routes to one screen is needed as a business requirement. (the storyboard starts to have lots of segues that are hard to keep track of). I think I'd like to try and remove the storyboard all together, and was wondering if anyone else has done the same. However, I'd love to hear more about your experience with a 'hybrid' approach.

Comment: would you prefer chat or an answer?

Comment: Go ahead and answer. I think that'll benefit the most people. -- Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Presenting the storyboard for my most complicated UI...

[image: Marked up Storyboard image]

This is all I need for (currently) six separate UI tabs, with an infinite ability to "dive into" multiple depths of view controller, to enable a user to find the data they are looking for.

**WARNING** **WARNING** **WARNING** 
I am concerned that a user may become "lost" in this maze. Please be careful with your UI design to ensure the user has some idea how "deep" they are into their data finding safari, or at least offer them with an easy method to "pop" their way back out.

I have my VCs/TVCs aligned in columns for ease of use - and as it turns out - ease of describing function.

The Tab Bar Controllers and Nav Controllers are self explanatory.

I will ignore the "Special Function" controllers for this exercise.

So lets focus on:

1. "Standard List" type TVCs,
2. "Detail Content" type TVCs, &
3. "Select from" type TVCs.

When a user selects a tab, the "Standard List" type TVCs provide the UI to display a list of items to the user. An add button (navigation bar item) provides the opportunity to manually add a new item to the list via a "Detail Content" type TVC.

**IB Segues from "Standard List" to "Detail Content" type TVCs**

A storyboard (IB created) segue from an item row in the "Standard List" triggers a segue to the "Detail Content" type TVC, so the user can review and/or edit the item data.

A storyboard (IB created) segue from the add button (navigation bar item) in the "Standard List" triggers a segue to a blank or "new" item in the "Detail Content" type TVC, so the user can add a new item and associated data.

**IB Segues from "Detail Content" to "Select from" type TVCs**

A storyboard (IB created) segue from an item row in the "Detail Content" triggers a segue to the "Select from" type TVC, depending on the type of data required for that content. (For example, one of the "Select from" type TVCs is a UIDatePicker embedded in a standard view controller, that enables the user to easily select a date and/or time.)

I arrived at the point where I wanted to begin jumping from "Select from" type TVCs back to "Detail Content" type TVCs.

I didn't even try doing this manually. My obsessive compulsive disorder required that my storyboard remain as pristine and as neat as practically possible - **NO** crazy segues "backwards" to facilitate the reuse of controllers.

So finally to an answer - yeah thanks for sticking with me - I thought the preamble is necessary.

For each class associated with the "Select from" type TVCs, I created a custom segue, embedded within the code of the TVC implementation file.

As I become more familiar with custom segues, I will probably remove these to a separate "helper" class.

But until then, the code at the top of each class implementation file of "Select from" type TVC...

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// Subclass of UIStoryboardSegue must override -perform ///
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@interface Segue_YourCustomNameHere : UIStoryboardSegue

@end

@implementation Segue_YourCustomNameHere

- (void)perform {
    ThisSelectFromClass *sourceViewController = self.sourceViewController;
    [sourceViewController.navigationController pushViewController:self.destinationViewController animated:YES];
}

@end
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///         END of subclass of UIStoryboardSegue         ///
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


@interface ThisSelectFromClass ()

//private declarations

@end


@implementation ThisSelectFromClass

//implementation code

@end
```

Easy, right!

Next step? Provide the controllers that you'd like to reuse with a "Storyboard ID".

Head back to your Interface Builder / Storyboard file, and select the controller that you would like to reuse in code.

In the Identity Inspector, under the subheading "Identity", type in a "Storyboard ID". I like to prefix my storyboard IDs with "id_", as shown in the example image below. I will use this example in the sample code below so keep an eye out for that.

[image: Identity Inspector]

Next step? How to trigger a custom segue???

Back to your implementation file for the class (example above uses `ThisSelectFromClass`)

Lets suggest that the segue is required when the user taps a particular row of data.

The code...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *mainStoryboard = nil;
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = nil;

    UIViewController *destinationVC = nil;
    Segue_YourCustomNameHere *segue = nil;

    mainStoryboard = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"UIMainStoryboardFile"];
    storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:mainStoryboard bundle:nil];

    //  I check the appropriate path depending on the title of my TVC
    //  You may need to determine another check method.

    if ([self.title isEqualToString:<<the title string>>]) {
        destinationVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"id_DetailContentVC"];
        segue = [[Segue_YourCustomNameHere alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"segue_YourSegueIdentifierNameHere"
                                                              source:self
                                                         destination:destinationVC];
    } else if ([self.title isEqualToString:<<another title string>>]) {
        destinationVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"id_NextDetailContentVC"];
        segue = [[Segue_YourCustomNameHere alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"segue_YourNextSegueIdentifierNameHere"
                                                              source:self
                                                         destination:destinationVC];
    } else if... // as many iterations as necessary
        //  Repeat above
    } else {
        //  Do other stuff - maybe error checking?
    }

    //  And because I always incorporate a UISearchDisplayController and I'm too lazy to think about how I should remove it for this example...
    id object = nil;
    if (tableView == self.tableView) {
        object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    } else {
        object = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    //  Finally...
    [self prepareForSegue:segue sender:object];  // optional
    [segue perform];
}
```

And, just in case you require this and include the `// optional` line above...

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    id segueDestinationVC = segue.destinationViewController;

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segue_YourSegueIdentifierNameHere"]) {
        //  These two lines of code are examples only...
        [segueDestinationVC setTitle:[sender valueForKey:@"aSenderKey"]]; // example
        [segueDestinationVC setObjectID:[sender objectID]];               // example

    } else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segue_YourNextSegueIdentifierNameHere"]) {
        //  These two lines of code are examples only...
        [segueDestinationVC setTitle:[sender valueForKey:@"aSenderKey"]]; // example
        [segueDestinationVC setObjectID:[sender objectID]];               // example

    } else {
        //  Do other stuff - again maybe error checking?

    }
```

Hope this helps.